# FIngerprint device not detected

Tags: 18.04, fingerprint-reader

I am using asus vivobook s430u i had installed the driver but it still say not detected.I had installl the ppa repository and fprint-demo and both of them saying its not detected.

Comment: Could you identify the fingerprint scanner devide ID using `lsusb`? Maybe it is not compatible with fprint yet

Comment: Here is the result                                                                                             
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56c1 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub